# Single HTML file with hidden divs defaults to blank

Tags: html, css

I am creating a single file HTML page, where the content is hidden until the navigation is hit. Unfortunately, when I set this up with HTML/CSS, on the initial load, there is just a blank div. After I click on a link, the page works as expected, but upon opening, I do not get the desired result. How would I go about making it default to the #home div on the page load? Is this possible to do in pure CSS?

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#resume">Résumé</a></li>
          <li><a href="#education">Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#ui">UI Design</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="home">
            Div 1
        </div>
        <div id="resume">
            Div 2
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    color: #16a085;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans:700', sans-serif;
    color: #16a085;
    font-size: 45px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 75px;
}
ul {
    font-family: 'Open Sans:300', sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 110%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #34495e;
}

img {
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

p {
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 800px;
}

hr {
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-right: 800px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

#home, #resume, #education, #ui{
    display:none;
}
#home:target{
    display:block;
}
#resume:target{
    display:block;
}
#education:target{
    display:block;
}
#ui:target{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: What is your desired result? I have a feeling you don't notice that your text is there behind your navigation.

Comment: Naw, it isn't there.

Comment: Yeah, my b. I had that fixed after I made the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, and you also need to put your `home` last of the 4 div's in the markup.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#resume">Résumé</a></li>
  <li><a href="#education">Education</a></li>
  <li><a href="#ui">UI Design</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="ui">
  Div 4
</div>
<div id="education">
  Div 3
</div>
<div id="resume">
  Div 2
</div>
<div id="home">
  Div 1
</div>
```

CSS

```
#ui:target ~ #home,
#education:target ~ #home, 
#resume:target ~ #home,
#resume, #education, #ui{
    display:none;
}

#resume:target{
    display:block;
}
#education:target{
    display:block;
}
#ui:target{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: The home block is visible when you click on the resume button. It doesn't hide the home button.